# Imperative before と言う

Tags: grammar, imperatives

Does using the imperative form (i.e., よこす　→　よこせ) before と言う mean "[He] said I have/had to..."?

I saw this sentence used: シートが砂で汚れたから、クリーニング代よこせと言いました！

I think this sentence basically means: Because I dirtied the seat with sand, [the taxi driver] said I had to pay the cleaning cost!

So, can using the imperative form of a verb mean "...said I had to..."?

And, if that is true, then could I make the following sentences?

- 行けと言う：says I have to go
- 野菜を食べろと言った：said I have to eat vegetables

お世話になります！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple imperative plus quoting particle. A basic "he told me to pay for the cleaning," or "tell me to go" or "told me to eat," essentially the same thing as what you offered as translations. It's a form of direct quotation and this doesn't really constitute a special case.

Comment: @yobisute, make sure you click the checkmark of the answer to show you've accepted this answer!

Comment: Linguistically, I believe this is called an indirect command.